# C# Removing dynamic created controls in a flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So the scenario is: `UserControl` with: 1 `GroupBox` inside: 2 `combobox`, 1 `textbox`, 1 `richtextbox` and 1 `button` for "remove the groupBox"

Form: 1 button(to add the `groupBox`) and a `flowLayoutPanel`

My problem: I can add as many `groupBox` components as I want, but when I click the button to "Remove the groupBox", in the "Form 1" if I do:

```
FlowLayoutPanel.Dispose()
```

I remove all the `GroupBox` components that were created, and in the `userControl` if I do:

```
GroupBox.Dispose();
```

It removes it but when I add another one it goes under the "One that was removed"

Here is the code I'm using:

**UserControl:**

```
private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   removeFunction();
}
```

**Form 1:**

```
Private void add_GroupBox(my class)
{
   myclass myClass = new myclass(datasource, null);
   flowLayoutPanel.Controls.add(myClass);
}


private void Remove_GroupBox()
{
   flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear(); // I know it removes all the groups created
   FlowLayoutPanel.Dispose(); // It does the same job

   // I just want the get the selected groupBox and dispose it or clear it
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know folks, that there is a little error in the UserControl because the function name is "Remove_GroupBox();" not "removeFunction();"
Maybe someone will understand wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

### First Option

You can add a button to your `User Control` to dispose itself.

```cs
this.Dispose();
```

### Second Option

You can add a property to your form to track selected User Control.

**Form1:**

```cs
public Control SelectedItem { get; set; } = null;

private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedItem != null)
    {
        SelectedItem.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**UserControl1:**

```cs
// You can use any Event you prefer (Enter, Click or etc.).
private void GroupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // First Parent is FlowLayoutPanel
   // Second Parent is your Form
   Form1 parent = this.Parent.Parent as Form1;
   if (parent != null)
   {
      parent.SelectedItem = this;
   }
}
```

Comment: WOOOOOW BRO, good job!!!
This.Dispose(); 
So easy worked so good looool i can't still believe that was so easy i tried a lot of things a lot of forum questions but this... THIS WAS SO NICE

I think i Love StackOverflow
StackOverFlow Is Love
StackOverFlow Is Life!